# Can I get list of Object with a list of another object inside in one query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to understand how can I get what I need in one query, I describe the situation:

**Tables in my DB :**

**User**(ID, Name, DateJoin,)           ----      ID is PK

**Profile**(ID, Name, DateCreated)  --- ID is PK

**UserProfile**(userID, profileID)    -- userID & profileID are both PK and FK.

*clarification : each user can have multiply profiles and each profile can be assigned to many users.

Now I have two classes in my application:

**AppUser**:

- ID
- Name
- DateJoin
- `List<AppProfile>` (List of profiles)

**AppProfile**:

- ID
- Name
- DateCreated

Now I want in one query to the DB to get the data I need in order to return a :

`List<AppUser>`, list of AppUser with in each AppUser I have a list of AppProfile that the specific AppUser have.

**Update:**

Ben answer is what I was looking for but there is one problem in his solution:

Its only returning user that have profiles, **users without profiles doesn't return.**

so for example I have 2 users, Jones with 2 profiles and Jim with none i get:

**Date-Table:**

**Row[0] :** User Name : "Jones", Profile Name: "one".

**Row[1]** : User Name : "Jones", Profile Name: "two".

There is no mention of Jim ( the other user that no profile associate with him.

There is any way to fix that problem ?

Comment: mysql <> sql-server - please use only the tag of the actual dbms you are targeting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need multiple queries - one to get all your app users then another to get your associated app profiles. Joining will only work on a 1:1 basis. You could concat all the related app profiles into a single column in your query then split them out in code but that's not ideal IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL for this is fairly straightforward, you just join all the tables. You will of course get as many records as their are combinations of users and profiles so you will have to iterate over the result set and populate your classes accordingly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM User u
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserProfile up on u.ID = up.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Profile p on p.Id = up.ProfileId
```

This would be neater with something like Entity Framework. Using that you could just create a many to many relationship and EF would do all the heavy lifting for you.

UPDATE:

As per your comment I have updated the query to always return all users, even if they have no profiles. UserProfile and Profile fields for these users will contain NULL.

Comment: Ben, one problem, if user doesnt have any profiles SQL doesnt return the user, just return the user who related to profiles.
but I want to get ALL users, any way to fix it?